# How to get root node in MEL Script?

Tags: while-loop, maya, mel

I have come across an existing piece of code that does this, but I assume there must be a better way. So, I need to get a highest level in mesh node in Autodesk Maya.

```
// List all mesh objects
string $nodess[] = `ls -type mesh` ;

// Replace existing items on active list with this
select -r $nodess[0] ;   

int $i = 1 ;

while ($i < 30) {
    // Pick up the tree 30 times
    pickWalk -d up ;
    $i++ ;
}

// List all selected objects
string $rootNode[] = `ls -sl` ;

// Clear selection
select -cl ;

string $myroot = $rootNode[0] ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the root, just string-split the long name:

```
global proc string get_root(string $node)
{
    string $longname[] = ls("-l", $node);
    string $tokens[];
    tokenize($longname[0], "|", $tokens);
    return $tokens[0];
}
```

Of course it's much more elegant in Python:

```
root = cmds.ls(node, l=True)[0].split("|")[0]
```

You could also re-write the orignal function by calling `listRelatives -p` until it returns nothing; but the string method is easier

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably the most direct:

```
string $roots[] = `ls -assemblies`;
```

From the Docs:

```
    -assemblies(-as)
        List top level transform Dag objects
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand this topic is a little out of date... However...

Theodox's answer helped me, but for some reason...

```
root = cmds.ls(node, l=True)[0].split("|")[0]
```

...didn't give me the exact answer I needed. Instead...

```
root = cmds.ls(node, l=True)[0].split("|")[1] #<-- Notice this [1]
```

gave me me the exact answer I needed. Apparently, [0] provides a blank space in my scene, because the array is listed as...

```
 [u'',u'the_Item_I_Need',u'etc1',u'etc2']
```

Just a helpful hint if someone is having an issue!!

Comment: always gives you a blank space at the 0 index in all scenes xd